# add_rewrite_rule behaving strangely

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm customizing another plugin by changing the rewrite rule, from:

```
    add_rewrite_rule('^api/auth/([0-9]+)?/?','index.php?__api=1&uid=$matches[1]','top');
```

to:

```
    add_rewrite_rule('^api/auth/','index.php?__api=1','top');
```

After making the change (and **not forgetting to refresh the permalinks**) my endpoint fails to work. When I attempt something like:

```
file_get_contents("http://mydomain.com/api/auth/")
```

...instead of the json object that should be returned, I get the user login form.
[image]

What's even weirder is that when I add an integer to the end like this:

```
file_get_contents("http://mydomain.com/api/auth/3")
```

...I get the json object that I expect! What's going on here?

Comment: it would seem your rewrite hasn't flushed. there are plugins, [like this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), that will let you see how the rules are being parsed. verify your rule is what you expect.

Comment: That's a nifty plugin. However, it shows the newly updated rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved this problem, but I'm still scratching my head about the "solution":

```
add_rewrite_rule('api/autho/?$','index.php?__api=1','top');
```

**This** version of the rewrite rule works for some reason. I'm guessing that there's some sort of namespace conflict that I accidentally stumbled across. Maybe `/auth/` is used somewhere else?